# Algorithm used in the sort method of Algorithm library in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

The `sort method` in Algorithm library in c++.

I want to know **which algorithm this method uses**. Is it fixed or the algorithm used depends upon the size of the input array.

*Before posting here I did Google search but couldn't get the answer.

Comment: It uses introsort (or at least most do AFAIK, since it isn't required).

Comment: It's up to the implementation AFAIK -- you may be able to get more specific information by looking at your particular compiler

Comment: VC++ seems to be using quicksort